# Is the sentence "You {verb}, I {verb}. I makes a difference." correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

Inspired to this sentence:

> KEEP CALM AND {*verb*}

I want to create my own, this is my current work:

> You {*verb*}, I {*verb*}. I makes a difference.

Example usage to that sentence template:

> You {*sleep*}, I {*pray*}. I makes a difference.
>
> You {*are sleeping*}, I {*am working*}. I makes a difference.

Is my sentence template sound good? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would change one thing in your examples:

You {verb}, I {verb}. I MAKE a difference.

The word make, when used with I in the present tense is make. If you used the word “he” or “she” makes would then be correct.

-I make a difference.

-He makes a difference

You do not need the “s” in your template.

Comment: ouh, what about without subject? for example in a brand tagline, it say "[BRAND NAME]. [make/s] a difference" should I use make or makes?

Comment: If the subject is singular, and not the personal pronouns _I_ or _you_, then 'makes'. Otherwise 'make'.